# Java Service Wrapper 3.2.3 on Mac OS X 64-bit

Tags: java, macos, wrapper, daemon

What's the best way to run an app using Java Service Wrapper 3.2.3 on Mac OS X 64-bit?

`sh.script.in` works, but there is no macosx-universal-64 version of the wrapper native binary (on JSW's 3.2.3 downloads page anyway http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/downloads/3.2.3/).

The result is the following error in the logs:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 | WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library because none of the
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |           following files:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |             libwrapper-macosx-x86-64.jnilib
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |             libwrapper-macosx-universal-64.jnilib
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |             libwrapper.jnilib
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |           could be located on the following java.library.path:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |             /Applications/EngineManager/.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |           Please see the documentation for the wrapper.java.library.path
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |           configuration property.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2009/08/20 14:47:15 |           System signals will not be handled correctly.
```

Also, when I try to restart the system, I get an error like:

```
Logout has timed out because the application ...WrapperSimpleApp failed to quit. ...`
```

I can't upgrade to a newer version of JSW because they went GPL.

Comment: Oh, and I tried renaming libwrapper-macosx-universal-32.jnilib to libwrapper-macosx-universal-64.jnilib, but JSW complains about that too.  Apparently you can't run a 64-bit version of the wrapper on a 64-bit JVM.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the Wrapper 3.2.3 source and compiled a macosx x86 64-bit version, which got rid of the native library warning.

I then noticed that I could restart the system from the command line with a `sudo`, and figured that the user-issued restart ("Apple Menu"/Restart) did not have permission to stop the service.  I thought perhaps the user-issued restart was trying to stop the service because it was using a java.awt.SystemTray tray icon.  I changed the service to run headless and voila, user-issued restart then executed without error.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you include the native library with the name libwrapper.jnilib in the libs folder of your project. For example `{App_Dir}/libs/libwrapper.jnilib`. Then link it in the wrapper.conf like this:

```
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib
```